# I am able to successfully run gem install bundler but still get "Could not find 'bundler'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

Setting up my old intel apple laptop running ventura 13.4.1, trying to create a brand new rails 7 app from scratch using ruby-3.1.3. I downloaded the latest command line tools. I run `gem install bundler --version 2.3.26 --default` and I get

```
Successfully installed bundler-2.3.26 as a default gem
```

and then the next line

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOENT)
    No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/specifications/gems/bundler-2.3.26
```

I run `gem install bundler` and I get

```
Successfully installed bundler-2.4.19
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.4.19
Done installing documentation for bundler after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

I run `gem list bundler` and I get

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (2.4.19, 2.3.26)
```

I run `bundler -v`
and I get

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (2.3.26) required by your /Users/kendallcarey/repos/broadway-blog/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.3.26`
```

I have tried running `gem install bundler:2.3.26` so many times which is the version in my **Gemfile.lock**. I've even run `gem update --system` and nothing's chanbged. How can I get `bundle install` to work?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it was the ruby version. I was able to run bundle install on the tab that was running the server and the new tab was using a different version of ruby.